# Adding and deleting a paragraph, displaying text briefly

Tags: javascript, html, function, parent-child, paragraph

After clicking on a specific place in an image map, the function `add()` should be run, a paragraph should be created, one should see "not available yet" in red for five seconds, and the paragraph should be deleted again.

```
function  add() {
    var x = document.createElement("P");
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    setTimeout ( "del()", 5000 );
        }
function del() {
removeChild() }
```

So there are a couple of things which are not correct.
1: how do you change the text to red? And to another font?
2: the `del()`function should remove the paragraph, but I don't know what to place there. Just `removeChild(P)` ? Wait... P isn't even a Child...

Could anyone help me with getting the desired result? (I mean, this: one should see 'not available yet' in red for five seconds, afterwards the paragraph should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change the text to red using JavaScript:

```
para.style.fontFamily = 'Arial'
para.style.color = 'red'
```

to change the text to red using CSS:

CSS:

```
.mypara {
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

JS:

```
para.className = 'mypara'
```

to remove the paragraph:

```
var para = document.createElement("P");
function  add() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(para);
    setTimeout (del, 5000);
}
function del() {
   para.parentNode.removeChild(para);
   // or if you just need to empty the paragraph
   // para.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: Probably better to give `para` a class and let CSS do the business. Easier to change in the future

Comment: Other improvement would be changing the global `para` variable to a third parameter to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Or make the del() function take the element as an argument and do `setTimeout(function(){ del(para) }, 5000);`

Comment: This is my code now. It still doesn't work... 
`function  add() {`
`var para = document.createElement("p");`
    `var t = document.createTextNode("Not available yet!");`
    `para.appendChild(t);`
    `document.body.appendChild(para);`
  `setTimeout(function(){ del(para) }, 5000);`
`};` 
`function del() {`
     ` document.body.removeChild(para);`
`}` What am I doing wrong? (@Ed Heal @Henrique Barcelos @I Stanley @user3896501)

Comment: try change `function del () ` to `function del(para)`

Answer (score 0):

**To make that text red:** There are two ways. Either you write:

```
x.style.color = '#ff0000';
```

Or you give it a class:

```
x.className = 'red_text'
```

... and define the style for that class in a stylesheet.

**To remove the paragraph**, just do the reverse of what you did to add it:

```
document.body.removeChild(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [example](https://jsbin.com/hazukiliza/edit?html,css,js,output).

> 1: how do you change the text to red? And to another font?

I suggest to use CSS for everything regarding style and simply assign the right class to the element. You can specify whatever you need. For example also use CSS for a fade in effect.

> 2: the del()function should remove the paragraph, but I don't know what to place there. Just removeChild(P) ?

I suggest to use a closure and pass parent and child in order to use *parent.removeChild(child);*. If you do not need nothing else you even could avoid to define another function.